# Out of memory on spit

Tags: clojure

I don't understand why my code raise an Out of memory exception.

I have an agent that call a function which append a line to the "test.log" file. The out of memory is on `PersistentHashMap $ BitmapIndexedNode.assoc(PersistentHashMap.java:624)`.

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(def the-agent(agent nil))

(defn process [_o content]

    (spit "test.log" content :append true)

)

(defn write-all []

    (doseq
        [x (range 1 5000000)]
        (send-off
            the-agent
            process
            "Line to be appended\n"
        )
    )

)
```

Thanks !

Comment: (agent nil) ?  I don't feel good about it

Comment: Because I don't use the value of agent. It stay to nil all the time. I just want to spit the file, a simple IO operation.

Comment: So you are sending 'process' function to a nil?

Comment: Yes but process function don't use is first param which contains nil.

Comment: Well if the file is too big, then getting OutOfMemory exception is expected. And we are talking about 5000000 here

Comment: But spit don't load all the file in memory no ? It uses a Buffered writer with append true. Is it false ?

Comment: And 5 000 000 of lines weigh only 100Mo in a file. I think if the file is correctly opened and closed, there is no out of memory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dispatched sends are blocked on I/O on the individual spits. The dispatches are created much faster than they can be completed and are accumulating.

```
(defn write-all [] 
  (doseq [x (range 1 5000000)] 
    (send-off the-agent process "foo") 
    (when (zero? (mod x 100000)) 
  (println (. the-agent clojure.lang.Agent/getQueueCount)))))


user=> (write-all)
99577
199161
298644
398145
497576
596548
Exception in thread "nREPL-worker-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Why this is causing "OutOfMemory" Exception?

Comment: This make sense. Thank you, we investigate.

Comment: @Chiron Accumulating memory overhead per dispatch at hundreds of thousands of outstanding dispatches.

Comment: Ready to crash my REPL now, so there's an edit showing the accumulation of the dispatch queue until memory is exhausted, reported every 100K sends. Notice that send-offs are completing, just not nearly fast enough to keep up with the demand.

Comment: with 16 gigs of ram and an SSD this example fails to kill the REPL, I had to add a call to (Thread/sleep 100) to the process function.

Comment: The agent process IO is too low. You are right. Thank you. I can solve my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

When you have many agents running blocking (or just long) tasks at the same time you can get into trouble with Clojure's default behaviour. By default `send-off` uses **unbounded parallelism** which tends to fall over in situations like this. Fortunatly in **Clojure 1.5 plus** you can set the execution strategy used by send-off to limit the degree of parallel execution

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(def the-agent (agent nil))
(defn process [_o content]
  (spit "test.log" content :append true))

(set-agent-send-executor!
  (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newFixedThreadPool 20))

(defn write-all []
  (doseq
      [x (range 1 5000000)]
    (send-off
     the-agent
     process
     "Line to be appended\n")))
```

which then completes with out running out of memory:

```
hello.core> (write-all)
nil
hello.core>
```

This is a **global change that affects all agents** in most cases it is preferable to make a thread pool specifically for this task and use `send-via` to use that specific pool:

```
(def output-thread-pool (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newFixedThreadPool 20))
(defn write-all []
  (doseq 
      [x (range 1 5000000)]
    (send-via output-thread-pool
     the-agent
     process
     "Line to be appended\n")))
```

This allows you to choose the **degree of parallelism you want** for each task. Just remember to shut down your thread pools when you are finished with them.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the same for `send`? It uses thread pool as well.

Comment: all calls to send use *the same* thread pool. Which means you can starve that thread pool by sending blocking operations to it. If you use send-via to specify a thread pool for your output tasks then output only blocks other output (which is blocked by the HD anyway) without starving the rest of the system.

Comment: send-off exists to allow a reasonable number of blocking operations without starving the system, and send-via is a newer extension to that for cases like this

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I understand better now. Just for my information, one last thing: you solution allows to break up the agent's internal storage accross the thread pool, thus avoiding it to blow up in memory, right?

Comment: After reading your question again I see that my answer does not actually address the problem you are seeing directly because you are using a single agent, and thus only ever running one task at a time.

Comment: Yes, its the dispatch queue of the single abused agent that's getting out of control. I can't tell from the question whether this code is meant to be reflective of the usage or just an abuse for the sake of the question. But, in reality you would not want to be enqueuing a bunch I/O flushes on another thread without being willing to wait for them at some point. Otherwise you've defeated the point of flushing. Either the agent should hold an open writer or the main thread should await the agent occasionally.